# perl hash array reading from files

Tags: regex, perl, foreach, hashtable

I'm trying to read multiple files that have the same format and want to make some statistics based on regex.

i.e I want to count similar items that are within the []

```
 NC_013618 NC_013633 ([T(nad6 trnE ,cob trnT ,)])
C_013481 NC_013479 ([T(trnP ,rrnS trnF trnV rrnL nad1 trnI ,)])
NC_013485 NC_003159 ([T(trnC ,trnY ,)])
NC_013554 NC_013254 ([T(trnR ,trnN ,)])
NC_013607 NC_013618 ([T(nad6 trnE ,cob trnT ,)])
```

the problem is that i'm not getting right values, below is my code:

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;

my %data;
@FILES = glob("../mitos-crex/*.out");
foreach my $file (@FILES) {
    local $/ = undef;
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    $data{$file} = <$fh>;
}

my @t;
my $c = 0;
foreach my $line (keys %data) {
    foreach my $l ($data{$line}) {
         print $l."\n";
        ($t[$c]) = $l =~ m/(\[.*\])/;

        $c++;
    }
}

#the problem is here the counter is not giving the right value

print $c;
my %counts;
$counts{$_}++ for @t;
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect `$data{$file} = <$fh>;` doesn't do what you want. Can you add a print just after and check whether it contains what you expect?

Comment: Add `use strict; use warnings;` and solve the errors/warnings that occur. Then re-post your question. And please use proper indentation.

Comment: @triple I printed $l and it gives right output

Comment: Please don't fix the problems in your original question. The answers you have received become irrelevant and it makes the question les useful in helping others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, *always* `use strict` and `use warnings`. This measure is vital for all programming, as it will quickly reveal simple problems that you may otherwise overlook or waste time on debugging. This is especially true and a simple courtesy if you are asking for others' help with your program

You seem to have become confused between *slurping* an entire file into a single string, and into an array of lines. The way you have written it, each element `$data{file}` is a single scalar value containing all of the file's data, and then you try to iterate over it with `foreach $l ($data{$line}) { ... }` which executes just once and so only find the first `[...]` string in the file

Ordinarily I would say that you shouldn't read in all of your file data in this way, as the problem is likely to have a better streamed solution, but I don't know what else you want to use the captured data for, so my solution follows your own design

I think you need to slurp the data into a virtual array, instead of a scalar, and then iterate over that in your loops. You must leave `$/` defined so that the file is read in lines, and build an anonymous array with `[ <$fh> ]`. Then you can iterate over the lines with `foreach my $line (@{ $data{$file} }) { ... }`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;

my @files = glob("../mitos-crex/*.out");

foreach my $file (@files) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
    $data{$file} = [ <$fh> ];
}

my $c = 0;
my @t;
foreach my $file (keys %data) {
    foreach my $line (@{ $data{$file} }) {
        ($t[$c]) = $line =~ /(\[.*\])/;
        $c++;
    }
}

print $c;
my %counts;
$counts{$_}++ for @t;
```

Answer (score 0):

The counter is giving a correct value. Your problem is that you are slurping the file (reading it all in at once), but then only storing the first value found:

```
($t[$c]) = $data{$line} =~ m/(\[.*\])/;  # only finds first value in file
```

Either loop over each file properly, and use the above regex for each line, or do something like:

```
push @t, ($data{$line} =~ m/(\[.*\])/g);
```

You should always use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

And solve the errors/warnings that result. Not doing so is a bad idea, and is only hiding the problems in your code -- not solving them.

Also, you should be aware that this statement:

```
foreach $l ($data{$line}) {
```

Only iterates *once*, because each "line" here is an entire file, and `$data{$line}` is besides a scalar value. Moreover, you iterate using `$l` as an alias, but you still use `$data{$line}` inside the loop, which makes the loop completely redundant.